# Cannot install couchdb2.1.1 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, 18.04, couchdb

I follow the instructions in this [link](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/install/unix.html#installation-using-the-apache-couchdb-convenience-binary-packages) using the bionic as the distribution name but keeps giving the message that there is no package called couchdb.

In the sources appears:

`deb https://apache.bintray.com/couchdb-deb/ bionic main`

and in this [link](https://apache.bintray.com/couchdb-deb/) appears the release for bionic.

However, after the:

```
$ curl -L https://couchdb.apache.org/repo/bintray-pubkey.asc \
| sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install couchdb
```

keeps saying the package does not exist:

```
...Ign:5 https://apache.bintray.com/couchdb-deb bionic InRelease                                                 
...A ler as listas de pacotes... Pronto
A ler as listas de pacotes... Pronto
A construir árvore de dependências       
A ler a informação de estado... Pronto
O pacote couchdb não está disponível, mas é referenciado por outro pacote.
Isso pode significar que o pacote falta, ou ficou obsoleto, ou
está disponível somente a partir de outra fonte

E: O pacote 'couchdb' não tem candidato para instalação
```

Comment: Please follow your link https://apache.bintray.com/couchdb-deb ... to know that the latest version is "16.04 Xenial". ... No packages for "18.04 Bionic". ... ... `couchdb` : https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=couchdb&searchon=names

Comment: Hello, the documentation of couchdb is not updated. There is a bionic package release: https://apache.bintray.com/couchdb-deb/dists/bionic/

Comment: It is solved with the new release of couchdb 2.1.1. It installs easily like it was supossed to happen.